# VF Displayed on Objects when the Object creating and Updating

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

This is my woking Code
    **VF Page:**

```
 <apex:page standardController="Account"  extensions="NewAndExistingController" id="demoId" >      
       <apex:form >    
          <apex:pageBlock >
       <apex:commandButton value="Call visualforce Page" action="{!click}"/>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
   </apex:page>
```

**controller:**

```
 public class NewAndExistingController {
 Public Account a= new Account();
 public NewAndExistingController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
  try{
     a =[select id,name from account where id=:controller.getId()];

  }catch(exception e){}
 }  
public PageReference click() {
PageReference openvfpage = New Pagereference('/apex'+'/XXXXVF'+'?aid='+a.id);//calling to another VF page
openvfpage.setRedirect(false);
return openvfpage ;  
}
public NewAndExistingController() {  } 
  }
```

Now I have attached this VF page to Account Object,Right now it showing,But now I Update same Account it not showing the our VF page,After Account Updated it showing the VF page,But I need to when the user update the Account at the same time it showing the VF page?.I want whenever user the click the Standard Account Button "Edit" is clicked at same time should be displays the our VF page.If it is possible please let me know.

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: before you create your Account you wont have Id of the record and hence the issue.Please be specific on what you are trying to do and where it went wrong

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct.I want when the account is update at the time shows the my VF page.Please let me know

Comment: Ramesh You will need to insert data first and then navigate to new page that you mention .After record insertion you will get Id

Comment: Ramesh, just wanted to say kudos for re-writing the question and adding a lot more information. Welcome to the site :)

Comment: I modified my question can you please check and let me know.

Comment: You have asked the same question 3 times with different titles. Please focus on one of those questions and delete the other two. You'll get better quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make your Visualforce edit page a section on the standard New and Edit layouts as a section like you can for the view/detail page.  However, you can override the New button and Edit buttons with a Visualforce page that uses the standardController for that Object, and extensions if you desire.  You would need to provide all functionality, though, not just your section.

See the [documentation on Overriding Buttons](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_customize_override.htm) for how to override the New and Edit buttons.